# React Passing Data to Components with JSX vs Native Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

This should be a simple one. I'm using JSX and ES6 with Babel to transpile my JSX and ES6, and those aspects are definitely working. However, when I'm running into a stumbling block with trying to pass data to the `ContactItem` Component via a JSX styled call. See the simple example below...

```
const contacts = [
    {key: 1, name: "Bob"},
    {key: 2, name:"Dude"}
  ]

class ContactItem extends React.Component {
   ...
}

// the following Javascript call works to loop through each contact and pass the data to ContactItem 
const contactListItems = contacts
  .map(contact => { return React.createElement(ContactItem, contact); });

// While using JSX, the contact data is not flowing through to ContactItem.
const contactListItemsJSX = contacts
  .map(contact => { return <ContactItem contact /> });
```

Why is the data not being passed when using `<ContactItem contact />`?

Comment: *"Why is the data not being passed when using <ContactItem contact />?"* Because `<ContactItem contact />` means that `ContactItem` is passed the *boolean* prop `contact`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of

```
React.createElement(ContactItem, contact);
```

in JSX is

```
<ContactItem {...contact} />;
```

See [JSX Spread Attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

is the syntax correct? It looks like you need to enclose with brackets.

```
const contactListItemsJSX = contacts.map(contact => { return (<ContactItem contact />) });
```